# Create Sharepoint 2007 subsite dynamically from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0

I would like to create subsites dynamically when a certain workflow is completed. The name of the site would be specified as part of the workflow. Is this possible?

Note: I do not have the ability to do any coding -- just stuff I can do through sharepoint designer and the regular sharepoint website interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to design the workflow in SPD, you ironically will need a custom workflow activity to create the site. Fortunately, there are third party custom activity packs that you can purchase and install on your farm that provide these, e.g:

http://www.virtosoftware.com/wikis/sharepoint-workflow-designer/sharepoint-site-amp-group-management-activities.aspx

Comment: Thank you. That appears to be exactly what I need. If only it were free!